# Reveal Icon Button - Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to create a reveal icon inside button on hover in TB3. I tried to mimic this behavior using CSS transitions and position property. But I essentially need is to have a separate background color for icon and button. Here is what I am doing right now.

**HTML Markup**

```
<button class="btn btn-dark icon-revealed">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span>
    Download
</button>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.btn.icon-revealed > span {
    left: -30px;
    width: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.btn.icon-revealed:hover > span {
    width: 20%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(2em,0);
    -moz-transform: translate(2em,0);
    -o-transform: translate(2em,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(2em,0);
}
```

**What I want to Achieve**

[image]

Notice the background color of icon and button changed on hover state. I could not able to do that. How can I achieve this in TB3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative way that smooths out the transition.

```css
.btn-dark {
  border: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn-dark:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn-icon {
  background: #4E7878;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.btn-icon span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.btn-icon:before {
  background: #4A6B6B;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 2.5;
  font-size: 150%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn-download:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(25%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(25%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(25%);
  transform: translateX(25%);
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-download:before {
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
}
.btn-download:hover:before {
  left: 0%;
}
.icon-reveal:before {
  content: "\e197";
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn-dark btn-icon btn-download icon-reveal"><span> Download</span>

  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create that effect using multiple backgrounds with `linear-gradient`. *Code explanantion in comments*

```css
.btn.icon-revealed {
  margin: 10px; /* Added for SO snippet, not required */
  width: 115px; /* Added fixed width for avoiding jump */
}
.btn.icon-revealed > span {
  left: -40px; 
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.btn.icon-revealed:hover > span {
  width: 20%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(2.5em, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(2.5em, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(2.5em, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(2.5em, 0);
}

/* Added code */
.btn.icon-revealed {
  background: #53777A; 
  color: #fff;
}
.btn.icon-revealed:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #4B6B6E 0%, #4B6B6E 30%, #53777A 30%);
                      /*  Start color---^,         End at 30%-^, ^-- Start second color */
  color: #fff;
}
.btn.icon-revealed:hover .text {
  padding-left: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button class="btn btn-dark icon-revealed">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span>
  <span class="text">Download</span>
</button>
```