# Add CSS transition inside of my button

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I would like to apply a transition inside of my button to have something like this: I want to move the letters inside to the left and also the icon appears and moves to the left when we select the button.

Before transition:
[image]

After transition:
[image]

I tried the following and it does not WORK!
What's going wrong?

```css
.button.button-reveal span {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease, right 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: left 0.3s ease, right 0.3s ease;
  transition: left 0.3s ease, right 0.3s ease;
}

.button.button-reveal:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  //position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0 22px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif, 'Lato';
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #00a2dc;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.button.button-rounded {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.button.button-reveal {
  padding: 0 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button.button-large {
  padding: 0 26px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
}

.button-teal {
  background-color: #00a2dc;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h2 class="panel-title">Access This Service</h2>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
  <ol class="leftmargin-sm nobottommargin">
    <li>test <a href="http://google.com">test</a></li>
    <li>test.</li>
    <li>test. </li>
    <li>test.</li>
  </ol>
  <a href="http://google.com" class="button button-rounded button-reveal button-large button-teal"><i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Go there now!</span></a><br> Note: test <a href="http://google.com">google.com</a>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is that you've set a transition for the `left` and `right` properties, but you are not changing those properties upon hover.

Below, I've set the transition for for `all` on the `<i>` element. Upon hover, I change from `width:0;` to `width:1em;margin-right:1em;`

For more reference, see [Using CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

```css
.button-reveal i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.button.button-reveal:hover i {
  width: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0 22px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif, 'Lato';
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #00a2dc;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button.button-rounded {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.button.button-reveal {
  padding: 0 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button.button-large {
  padding: 0 26px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
}

.button-teal {
  background-color: #00a2dc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href="http://google.com" class="button button-rounded button-reveal button-large button-teal"><i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true">&#xbb;</i><span>Go there now!</span></a>
```

---

### Edit

In this example, I've animated the icon's `left` property to bring it into view and the `margin` of the text to shift it to the right.

```css
.button-reveal i {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 45px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-align: center;
  left: -100%;
  transition: left 0.25s ease;
}
.button-reveal:hover i {
  left: 0;
}

.button-reveal span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2em;
  transition: margin 0.35s ease;
}
.button-reveal:hover span {
  margin: 0 1em 0 3em;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif, 'Lato';
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #00a2dc;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button.button-rounded {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.button.button-large {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
}
.button-teal {
  background-color: #00a2dc;
}
.button-reveal {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href="http://google.com" class="button button-rounded button-reveal button-large button-teal"><i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Go there now!</span></a>
```

Comment: That is not what I am trying to approach. I'm not moving the button to the left. I am moving the content of the button which is "GO THERE NOW!" to the left. As you can see in the first picture, the arrow icon is not initially in the button but once my cursor selects the button, it does appear and moves (from left to right). So in other words, the transition is applied to the words and the arrow icon. Both move from left to right.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm not moving the button to the left, either. I don't see how the content of the button is moving to the left in your mockups. I also don't understand what you're describing with the icon. But the concept is the same: you have the change the property you want to transition.

Comment: I tried everything and I can't get it to work. Do you have any code you can share with me?

Comment: in my case I want to move <span>Go there now!</span> to the left. and the icon to the left as well <i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true">

Comment: Can you show me the changes you've made? Do you mean you want the icon to slide leftward out from the left side of the button? Do you see what I mean about changing the property you want to transition? The property you're transitioning has to change from *some value* to a *different value* upon hover.

Comment: I see. I adjusted my example accordingly, but the concept is the same.

Comment: [Here's another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676050/reveal-icon-button-bootstrap-3#answer-32676842) using CSS `transform` instead of `margin`.